# WSO2 API manager: how to replace a specific part of the request URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm new to WSO2 API Manager and I need to expose a series of APIs that we could simplify to:

- GET mywso2:8243/**example/v1/tag**/test
- POST mywso2:8243/**example/v1/tag**/anothertest

Every call to these EPs must be redirected to:

- GET myserver:8080/**process/tag/v1**/test
- POST myserver:8080/**process/tag/v1**/anothertest

How can I achieve such a result? I tried checking the documentation but couldn't find a solution where the path is partially changed as I would need.

Answer (score 0):

Create your API like below. Then you can invoke it as `https://localhost:8243/example/v1/test1` which will call `http://myserver:8080/process/tag/v1/test1`

[image]

If you need to change the backend version dynamically you may have to add a custom mediation policy to your API.